# Why does the French sixth sound more dissonant than the others?

Tags: chords, harmony

The French sixth chord sounds more dissonant than the Italian and German sixth chords.  What is the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the French 6th chord has an extra tritone.

If we take an Ab Augmented 6th chord, we would have:

`Ab C D F#`

`Ab` to `D` and `C` to `F#` are both tritones.

By contrast, the Italian and German versions would only have one: `C` to `F#`.

Comment: So, it is like a diminished 7th(which is also 2 overlapping trritones) but based on the major chord instead?

Comment: @Caters I've never thought about it that way.  It's true that they both contain two tritones, but their harmonic function is different enough that I'm not sure it is a fruitful line of thinking in any deep sense.  But I suppose it does explain why they have similar amounts of dissonance. (The whole step in the FrAug6 is why it sounds even clashier than then dim7)

Comment: Ah, now I got it!  While the Italian and the German sixth chords have only one, the French sixth has TWO tritones, the A4 / d5 intervals, which are ***EXTREMELY*** dissonant.  The tritones are known as "Devils", which were banned in early church music!